# How To Create An Excel Type Grid Application In SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, custom-list, excel, custom

I have a requirement to create an application in SharePoint 2010 where the user interface presented is like a grid/spreadsheet.  But each cell in the grid needs to represent a SharePoint item in a SharePoint list in the background.

Each cell will record data such as comments, a time and a colour (the colour is important for the UI as it links back to a project). I know about data sheet view but this does not have all the functionality that is needed for a slick UI.

I have seen some web based grids like jqxGrid but I don't know how to implement the one cell to one list item relationship in the application in this frameworks.

Or I could try SPGridView but this may not go far enough to create a slick UI that is required.

Could somebody give me some direction or suggestions/help please?

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint 2010 supports client object model.

So using client object model (JavaScript) get all the data from the list (into any format of your choice). Another option is using the web services (spservices) or REST endpoints to get the data.

Then use that to bind to any of the jQuery grid control.

Handle the grid events and on those event use client object model code to post the data back.